# Force User to enable location before log in - ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: google-maps, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on ASP.NET MVC 5 Razor based web application. I want to implement GPS Tracking. I want to force user to allow access to its location when he hits login button after entering username and password.

So when user enters username and password and hits submit button, I want to show pop up saying 'Do you want to give access to your location?'. If he says yes, then he should be signed in other wise the request does not move forward.

I tried to search but could not find anything upto my needs.

Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

You can read about getting user consent and having a fallback if geolocation is required right [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/device-access/user-location/user-consent?hl=en)

Comment: It's nice to post most important link content on SO in case link'a content will be removed.